# Yii2 uploading files returns failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, ajax

Am uploading a file via ajax following this link
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055274/upload-ajax-file-in-yii2) ive been able to pass the files via ajax but am getting another error when moving the files

I dont want to provide an absolute path in my code like since different codes are used in different areas of the application so i prefer to use the getalis to return the actual path

This is what i have

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, Yii::getAlias("@uploads/siteimages/slider/").$filename);
```

This is the filename

```
$file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['TblSlider']['name']["file"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $filename = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:m:s")).".".$file_ext;
```

Previously i tried using the getUploadedinstance but since its an ajax request it fails

By doing

```
var_dump($_FILES["TblSlider"]["tmp_name"])  It returns the actual tmp file
```

The path exisit where i wrong

Answer (score 0):

//Set the path that the file will be uploaded to

```
$path = Yii::getAlias('@frontend') .'/web/uploads/'

 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, Yii::getAlias("@uploads/siteimages/slider/").$filename);
```

Try by changing Alias path like this

```
   Yii::getAlias('@frontend') .'/web/uploads/'
```

Help Url : [How to upload files in web folder in yii2 advanced template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799483/how-to-upload-files-in-web-folder-in-yii2-advanced-template)